# Better way to get rid of 'borrowed value does not live long enough'

Tags: rust

I am taking part in Advent of Code. In one of my programs I get a:
'borrowed value does not live long enough'

I did found a way around it, but am not really happy about it and was wondering if there is a better way.
My the code is:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::path::Path;


fn main() {
    let mut coloured_cubes  = HashMap::from([
        ("red",   0),
        ("green", 0),
        ("blue",  0),
    ]);
    let mut game_nr         = 0;
    let mut sum_of_powers   = 0;

    let file                = std::env::args().nth(1).
        expect("Please specify a filename");


    if let Ok(lines) = read_lines(file) {
        for line in lines {
            if let Ok(mut cal_line) = line {
                game_nr += 1;
                coloured_cubes.insert("red",   0);
                coloured_cubes.insert("green", 0);
                coloured_cubes.insert("blue",  0);
                let prefix  = format!("Game {game_nr}: ");
                if ! cal_line.starts_with(&prefix) {
                    panic!("Line {game_nr} had a wrong prefix");
                }
                cal_line.replace_range(..prefix.len(), "");
                for game_part in cal_line.split("; ") {
                    for cube in game_part.split(", ") {
                        let cube_info: Vec<&str> = cube.split(' ').collect();
                        if cube_info.len() != 2 {
                            panic!("{prefix} wrong format '{cube}'");
                        }
                        let count  = cube_info[0].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
                        let colour = cube_info[1];
                        if count < 1 {
                            panic!("{} count should at least be 1 {:?}",
                                prefix, cube_info);
                        }
                        if ! coloured_cubes.contains_key(colour) {
                            panic!("{prefix} illegal colour {colour}");
                        }
                        if count > coloured_cubes[colour] {
                            let temp_colour = match colour {
                                "red"   => "red",
                                "green" => "green",
                                "blue"  => "blue",
                                _       => panic!("Got a wong colour: {colour}")
                            };
                            coloured_cubes.insert(temp_colour, count);
                        }
                    }
                }
                sum_of_powers += coloured_cubes["red"] *
                    coloured_cubes["green"] * coloured_cubes["blue"];
            } else {
                panic!("Problem with line");
            }
        }
    } else {
        panic!("Did not get any lines!");
    }
    println!("ResultSum of powers: {sum_of_powers}");
}


// Functions
// The output is wrapped in a Result to allow matching on errors
// Returns an Iterator to the Reader of the lines of the file.
fn read_lines<P>(filename: P) ->
io::Result<io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>>>
where P: AsRef<Path>, {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    Ok(io::BufReader::new(file).lines())
}
```

The solution is the usage of the temp_colour variable. It is doable, because there are only three colours, but if there would be many more, it would become an headache.

The problem is that colour is created from cal_line which goes out of scope while coloured_cubes keeps existing and I did an insert in it with colour.

If I change:

```
    coloured_cubes.insert(temp_colour, count);
```

into:

```
    coloured_cubes.insert(colour, count);
```

I get:

```
   Compiling Day02 v0.1.0 (/home/cecil/Rust/AdventOfCode/2023/Day02)
warning: unused variable: `temp_colour`
  --> src/bin/part2.rs:48:33
   |
48 | ...                   let temp_colour = match colour {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_temp_colour`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

error[E0597]: `cal_line` does not live long enough
  --> src/bin/part2.rs:32:34
   |
22 |             if let Ok(mut cal_line) = line {
   |                       ------------ binding `cal_line` declared here
23 |                 game_nr += 1;
24 |                 coloured_cubes.insert("red",   0);
   |                 -------------- borrow later used here
...
32 |                 for game_part in cal_line.split("; ") {
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
60 |             } else {
   |             - `cal_line` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
warning: `Day02` (bin "part2") generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `Day02` (bin "part2") due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

I tried to copy, to clone, to Box, …, but until now only creating a temp_colour variable solved my problem.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Please edit your question to include definitions for `read_lines`, `game_nr`, and `coloured_cubes`. Also, edit your question to include the exact error message you're seeing.

Comment: Hopefully now that the important parts of this have been identified, you can make a [mre] out of it.

Comment: The problem was that when you do an insert the key value is a value that goes out of scope. By using get_mut instead of insert the problem goes away.

Comment: I see that the question was voted down two times. What is so wrong with this question? (So I can ask a better one next time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *kind* of solution you used isn’t that bad, although it’s easier to see (and cleaner) when you use a better type for the key, like an `enum` – you’re parsing text into a fixed set of values (of `&'static str`s in your program).

```
enum Colour {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
}

// parsing is a normal thing to do!
match colour_name {
    "red" => Colour::Red,
    "green" => Colour::Green,
    "blue" => Colour::Blue,
    _ => panic!("bad colour"),
}
```

But in this case, you know the key already exists in the map, so you can use `get_mut` to replace the existing value without worrying about passing ownership of a new key to the hashmap (which is the issue):

```
*coloured_cubes.get_mut(colour).unwrap() = count;
```

If the keys were dynamic, that’s when you would turn to `String`:

```
let mut coloured_cubes: HashMap<String, i32> = HashMap::new();
```

```
if count > *coloured_cubes.get(colour).unwrap_or(&0) {
    coloured_cubes.insert(String::from(colour), count);
}
```

Comment: If there are only 3 colors known at compile time, it's probably better to use a `struct Colors { red: usize, green: usize, blue: usize }` with an accessor `fn get_color(&mut self, color: Color) -> &mut usize;`. The map overhead is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @cdhowie: Yes, it is, and you should probably make that an answer.

Comment: I want to keep it as generic as possible. Say that you also have to read the colours, then my current version keeps working with minimal changes.  
I came also to the HashMap<String, i32> solution, but instead I used:   
coloured_cubes.insert(colour.to_string(), count);  
But I think I try the get_mut variant.

Comment: The only thing that I changed to the original program is that I use now get_mut instead of insert. I did not even change the HashMap definition. Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change (with thanks to Ry-):

```
                if count > coloured_cubes[colour] {
                    let temp_colour = match colour {
                        "red"   => "red",
                        "green" => "green",
                        "blue"  => "blue",
                        _       => panic!("Got a wong colour: {colour}")
                    };
                    coloured_cubes.insert(temp_colour, count);
                }
```

for:

```
                    if count > coloured_cubes[colour] {
                        // Can not use coloured_cubes.insert(colour, count)
                        // because colour goes out of scope
                        *coloured_cubes.get_mut(colour).unwrap() = count;
                    }
```

I also changed:

```
            coloured_cubes.insert("red",   0);
            coloured_cubes.insert("green", 0);
            coloured_cubes.insert("blue",  0);
```

tot the must more robust:

```
            for value in coloured_cubes.values_mut() {
                *value = 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that coloured_cubes went out of scope, but I do not need it out of scope any-more. So another solution would be to define colour_init:

```
    let colour_init         = [
        ("red",   0),
        ("green", 0),
        ("blue",  0),
    ];
```

and change the start of the code to:

```
    if let Ok(lines) = read_lines(file) {
        for line in lines {
            if let Ok(mut cal_line) = line {
                let mut coloured_cubes  = HashMap::from(colour_init);
```

and then the following is no problem:

```
                        if count > coloured_cubes[colour] {
                            coloured_cubes.insert(colour, count);
                        }
```